# How to obfuscate android .apk file using proguard using android studio?

Tags: android, android-proguard

I want to obfuscate my android apk file using proguard or any other method. tried many ways including :-

- copy-pasting proguard.txt and proguard-optimise.txt file from sdk folder (sdk-tools-progurad) to my app module within the project directory
- I have written minifyEnabled=true in gradle file of app.

After doing so facing further issue of some proguard errors giving warnings for external library class files. 
**Error**: -Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.

> java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.

Even I am unable to generate signed apk.

Comment: You need to analyze the list warnings and update the proguard-rules.pro file to fix the issues.

Comment: how to update and what to write in proguard-rules.pro ?? As per console one of the library com.rey.material is throwing errors. For that i have written -dontwarn com.rey.** in proguard-rules.txt file but still facing same issues. Able to generate debug version but failed to generate signed apk

Comment: What to write in proguard-rules.pro depends on the warnings. You may have to ignore more than one package.

Answer (score 0):

It is strongly advised to investigate the warnings that ProGuard prints to the console and try to fix them. For this you will have to either include additional libraries or add `-dontwarn` directives to your `proguard-project.txt` file.

As a last resort, you can also use `-ignorewarnings` which will instruct ProGuard to continue regardless of any remaining warning.